# Delete all files in the folder except one extension(say .idf) using batch file

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

My current code to delete all files in a folder older then 2 days is :

```
forfiles /p "C:\Test" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del /F /Q @path" /d 2
```

There is one **.idf** file among all other files. I want to delete all files except the one .idf file. What do I change to get the current code to ignore the file? If it is not possible, any new command will be helpful.

Comment: This is not working for me I tried this:
`for %i in (C:\Test\*) do if not %i == a.c del %i`

I entered this command in my batch file and ran it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve your approach a little:

- keep `forfiles` with `/d -2` switch to treat older files only
- use `for %G` with `if /I [%~xG] neq [.idf]` to omit files with `.idf` extension
- double all `%` if run from a batch file: `%%G` instead of `%G` etc.
- remove `@echo` no sooner than debugged.

The command:

```
forfiles /p "C:\Test" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c for %G in (@path) do @if /I [%~xG] neq [.idf] @echo del /F /Q %G" /d -2
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)